# How can someone participate in tribunal?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to know who analyses reports and is it possible to get that work? Mainly because I would just love to make this community better with what little I can do:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is go to http://na.leagueoflegends.com/tribunal/ and log in.  Once you log in, you will be presented with cases, where you can vote to Pardon, Punish, or Skip.  Also the tribunal is only accessible to those level 20 or higher.

When considering cases, remember [Riot's guidelines](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/tribunal/en/faq/#2):

> Generally speaking, a punishable offense must be a deliberate, malicious act that is intended to spoil another player’s experience. Here are some examples of situations that might constitute punishable offenses:
>
> - Explicit use of hate terms, racial slurs, cultural epithets, etc.
> - Players who deliberately and viciously insult other players.
> - Repeatedly negative, unconstructive attitudes
> - Players whose teasing crosses the line, and who persist after being asked repeatedly to stop.
> - Deliberately disruptive gameplay, such as intentional feeding.